# CakePHP - How to check which validation rule failed?

Tags: validation, cakephp

How can I check in my controller which one of the validation rules failed? I want to know if 'rule2' failed, based on the validation rule key.

```
public $validate = array(
    'email' => array(
        'rule1' => array(
            'rule' => array('email', true),
            'message' => 'Please enter a valid email address'
        ),
        'rule2' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'message' => 'Email address already registered'
        )
    ),
);
```

I know I can do `debug($this->User->validationErrors)` but all that shows is the message, and I don't want to check the message because I might change that in the future.

Is there any way to see that `'email.rule2'` failed, based on the validation rule key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me it never made sense that the default param for last is false

IMO the correct approach is:

```
public $validate = array(
    'email' => array(
        'rule1' => array(
            'rule' => array('email', true),
            'message' => 'Please enter a valid email address',
            'last' => true
        ),
        'rule2' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'message' => 'Email address already registered'
        )
    ),
);
```

ONLY check on unique if the email is valid in the first place.

and no, the message is the only thing returned. why is it important what failed?

Comment: Because if the email address is already registered I wanted to deal with the user action differently, such as providing a "Did you forget your password?" link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it does  exactly what you need but try this:

```
$errors = $this->ModelName->invalidFields();
```

Comment: Apparently, this returns the field name (`'name'`) and the **localised** error message in a numeric array. It won't use the `'rule2'` key at all.